# Importing drupal media from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9 through yaml

Tags: drupal, media, drupal-9

I'm migrating lots of images from a Drupal 8 site into Drupal 9. I want these to be media in the Drupal 9 site.

We have used the following YAML code and are trying to migrate the images in the media field.

```html
id: images_migration_test6
label: 'Migrate Images to Media and Files'
migration_groups:
  - 'custom_migrations'
 
source:
  plugin: embedded_data
  data_rows:
    - id: 1
      filename: 'image1.jpg'
      image_path: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg'
      created_at: '2022-01-26T12:00:00'  # Updated to ISO 8601 format
    - id: 2
      filename: 'image2.jpg'
      image_path: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Patras_from_the_fortress.jpg'
      created_at: '2022-01-26T14:30:00'  # Updated to ISO 8601 format
  ids:
    id:
      type: integer
 
process:
  bundle:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 'image'  # Media bundle type, adjust as needed
  name: filename
  field_media_image/target_id:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: images_migration_file
    source: image_path
  status:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1  # Published
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1  # User ID for the author of the media item
  created:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'  # Updated to match the format in the source data
    to_format: 'U'
    source: created_at
 
  # File Migration Configuration
  field_media_image__file:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: images_migration_file
    source: image_path
  field_media_image__alt:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 'Image Alt Text'  # Adjust as needed
 
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:media'
  default_bundle: image  # Media bundle type, adjust as needed
```

We got a success message, but the actual image is not migrating to the media field. Anybody please help on this?